# Unable to print images from internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I am having internet explorer 11. My machine is Windows 7 32 bit.

I am not able to print images using internet explorer.

Just I was loaded google. Press Ctrl + P and save as XPS document.

All the contents are present except images.

any patches are required?

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This actually is off-topic for SO, but... Open File|Print options and tick "Print background and images" checkbox.